# lwjgl request display close when undecorated

Tags: lwjgl

I want to create a custom titlebar/border for my display/window so I set the corresponding system property to "true" but how do I send a close request to the window manually to react to the `Display.isCloseRequested()`?

Answer (score 1):

Listen to a preferred event and then do System.exit(0);
Then you are good to go!
Bear in mind , LWJGL is a OpenGL wrapper , it doesnt include any widgets physics engines and stuff. So make your own button and listen for an event

Comment: Well it does feature the creation of a window for you that has a close requested flag - somehow I need to be able to set this flag ... right?

Comment: the Display.isCloseRequested() is false till the program gets a request (System.exit(0)) to close the window

Comment: Ah - the reason this works is because of the registered shutdown hook that gets created when the window is created - (I did a bit of source digging here ...)

Comment: Sometimes on Apple systems , you need to call System.exit(0); after Display.destroy(). You just have to.